# Connect to WCF Web Service using Jquery and Soap-XML

Tags: javascript, web-services, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a simple WCF web service  I tried to connect  with jquery and SOAP-XML ( dataType: "xml" ) .but when i send my request i get "BAD REQUEST Error 400" from my server.
here is my SOAP-XML:

```
var soapMessage =
            '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"> \
             <soap:Header> \
             <Action soap:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none\">http://tempuri.org/IService/HelloWorld</Action> \
            </soap:Header> \
            <soap:Body> \
            <HelloWorld xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> \
            </HelloWorld> \
            </soap:Body> \
            </soap:Envelope>';
```

and this is my $.Ajax :

```
var productServiceUrl = 'http://localhost:3523/Service.svc/HelloWorld';
    $.ajax({
                url: productServiceUrl,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: soapMessage,
                complete: endSaveProduct,
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
                async: true,
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);

                }

            });
```

and here is Detail of Request and Responce (I trace this in Google Chrome):

Request Hedear

> ```
> POST /Service.svc/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: localhost:3523
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Length: 550
>
> Origin: http://localhost:3523
>
> X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.15 Safari/535.2
>
> Content-Type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
>
> Accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
>
> Referer: http://localhost:3523/WcfService.htm
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
> ```

and my Response Header

```
    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

    Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0

    Date: Wed, 04 Jan 2012 14:56:06 GMT

    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

    Cache-Control: private

    Content-Length: 0

    Connection: Close
```

Request payload:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">                  <soap:Header><Action soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService/HelloWorld</Action>                 </soap:Header><soap:Body><HelloWorld xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"></HelloWorld></soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>
```

and this if my WCF web service:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    String HelloWorld();
```

Comment: i tried this with ( .asmx) web service and it work correctly .but when i want to use it to call a wcf webservice it return Bad Request(400)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the way. I use this solution :
 this is my Web Service interface :

```
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    //[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/data?id={value}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetData(int value);

}
```

this is my impliment of this function in Web service :

```
public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
```

and here is the Script to connect to WCF Web servise:

```
<script type="text/javascript">



    $(document).ready(function () {
        var bhRequest = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
            "<s:Body>" +
            "<GetData xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" +
            "<value>10</value>" +
            "</GetData>" +
            "</s:Body>" +
        "</s:Envelope>";
        $("#btnWCFBasicHttp").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Service.svc",
                data: bhRequest,
                timeout: 10000,
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IService/GetData");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $(data).find("GetDataResponse").each(function () {
                        alert($(this).find("GetDataResult").text());
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(error);

                }
            });
        });
    });


</script>
```

remember the WCF (`url: "Service.svc"`) is near my html Page.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you so much. I'm newbe with WCF so I experimented with your code a little. After removing `[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]` code will still work. Why so?

Comment: WebMessageFormat.Json is defult config